# Check local server after reboot

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

I have an Apache web server running on Linux, which I reboot with a PHP script.
Can I use Javascript or PHP to detect when the server is back up?

Comment: If your webserver starts when the machine is turned on you can take a look at the [source](https://github.com/sjparkinson/isitup) to https://isitup.org/ for a php solution.

Answer (score 1):

If you run a recurring Ajax request to a PHP script on the server, you can check for a specific response.

```
setInterval(function(){
    jQuery.get(URL, function( response ){
        if(response.data)
            alert('Server is back');
    }, 'json');
}, 1000);
```

The example code polls a URL every second, and if the server is up, it alerts. I'd replace alert with a div on the page with the server status, but if it were me, though.

In PHP, you'd run something like:

````
<?php
echo json_encode( array( 'data' => 'true' ) );```
````

Answer (score 0):

With php you can use [fsockopen](http://php.net/manual/en/function.fsockopen.php) for that :

```
function pingServer($host,$port=80,$timeout=6)
{
        $fsock = fsockopen($host, $port, $errno, $errstr, $timeout);
        if ( ! $fsock )
        {
                return FALSE;
        }
        else
        {
                return TRUE;
        }
}
```

I.E.:

```
if(pingServer("http://yousite.com")){echo "I'm up";}else{echo "I'm down";}
```